# Windows equivalent of VISUAL or EDITOR environment variables

Tags: windows, terminal, editor

On Unix systems, a normal pattern for asking a user to edit some sufficiently complex text is to open the editor specified in the `VISUAL` or `EDITOR` environment variables and point that editor at a temporary file initialized with the content you want the user to edit. Is there some equivalent of this pattern on Windows, and if so, how does it work?

Comment: No, there isn't. Unix is based on text files, so it makes sense to have a single centralized "standard" editor set by those env vars. Windows config is "anything goes", so it's pointless to have a standard editor. "let's open this binary garbage with notepad. what could go wrong?" And for config options stored in the registry, notepad would be worse than useless.

Comment: Is there some way of accomplishing the same outcome on Windows? What do CLI tools for Windows do to solve this problem?

Comment: like I said, there's no standard editors in windows, so there's no way to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your app to open config file for editing for user, you can do it like this (C++):

```
if( (INT_PTR)ShellExecute( NULL, "open", "config.json", NULL, NULL, SW_SHOWDEFAULT) <= 32 )
    if( (INT_PTR)ShellExecute( NULL, "open", "notepad.exe", "config.json", NULL, SW_SHOWDEFAULT) <= 32 ){
        MessageBox( ourHwnd, "Fail to open editor. Please edit config.json", "Error", MB_ICONERROR );
    }
```

That will first attempt to open "config.json" like Windows will do if user would double click on it.
I assume that if user have favorite text editor, he/she will associate that editor with *.json, *.txt, and other text files.
If that fail, then lunch notepad with "config.json" as argument.
That should not fail, but I once saw user removing notepad to have more space on hard disk, so it can fail, so if that fail then just display error message.

According to [microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-shellexecutea) `ShellExecute` can take "edit" as second argument. So it looks like functionality like this exists or was planed, but I'm not awere of any option for user to change what edit does in Windows. So I wouldn't use that.